MiddlewareMixin.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'get_response'
I have created a custom django middleware and decorator to authenticate the RESTful API that I am developing. Here is the code of the middleware that I have developed:
# myproject/middleware.py

import jwt
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import JsonResponse
from users.models import User

class JWTAuthenticationMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        excluded_paths = ['/auth/users/register/', '/auth/users/login/']

        if any(request.path.startswith(path) for path in excluded_paths):
            return self.get_response(request)  # Skip JWT validation for excluded paths

        token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')
        if token:
            try:
                decoded = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=["HS256"])
                user = User.objects.get(id=decoded['id'])
                request.user = user
            except (jwt.ExpiredSignatureError, jwt.InvalidTokenError, User.DoesNotExist):
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid or expired token'}, status=401)
        else:
            request.user = None

        return self.get_response(request)

This is the code for the decorator:
# users/utils.py

from functools import wraps
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.middleware.csrf import CsrfViewMiddleware

def token_required(view_func):
    @wraps(view_func)
    def _wrapped_view(view_class_instance, request, *args, **kwargs):
        csrf_middleware = CsrfViewMiddleware()

        # Check CSRF token
        csrf_error = csrf_middleware.process_view(request, None, (), {})
        if csrf_error:
            return csrf_error

        if not request.user:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Token is missing or invalid'}, status=401)

        return view_func(view_class_instance, request, *args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapped_view

Here is one of the views that are giving the error:
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from users.serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from users.models import User
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed
import jwt
from django.conf import settings
from users.utils import token_required

class UserView(APIView):
    @token_required
    def get(self, request):
        token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')

        if not token:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated User!')

        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=['HS256'])
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            raise AuthenticationFailed("Token has expired! Login again")

        user = User.objects.filter(id=payload['id']).first()
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)

And the error is this:
MiddlewareMixin.init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'get_response'
I really need help with getting this to work. Versions of Python and Django that I am using are 3.12.3 and 5.0.4 respectively.
I have tried many different solutions but none worked so far. Even ChatGPT isn't able to find the issues in this small piece of code.

Please, [edit] the question and share the full traceback as code (not an image). Normally the Django error page has a function to turn the error in a text format that includes settings, traceback, etc.
